# Retarget logs for a specific class

Tags: c#, .net, logging, dependency-injection, serilog

I have a .NET 3.1 app.

While I'm fine with it logging information to console in general, there is one part (API client) where it generates tons of logs and it is too much for console. How to make it so that for a particular class logs go not to console but to a file?

Create 2 loggers?

Answer (score 1):

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.File(@"MyFile.txt")
    .WriteTo.Logger(lc => lc
        .Filter.ByExcluding(Matching.FromSource<ApiClient>())
        .WriteTo.Console())
    .CreateLogger();
```

Now everything will get written to MyFile.txt but any logs from inside ApiClient won't get output to console

Answer (score 0):

Another option, in case `Filter` gets a little complicated, is `WriteTo.Conditional`, which has extra support in *Serilog.Expressions*:

```
dotnet add package serilog.expressions
```

Then:

```cs
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.File("MyFile.txt")
    .WriteTo.Conditional(
        "SourceContext <> 'MyNamespace.ApiClient'",
        wt => wt.Console())
    .CreateLogger();
```

Comment: Is there a way to exclude certain interface from writing to comsole?

Comment: Not  by interface - only by concrete implementation type.